# C# Where int isn't null in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, null

I'm using C# in Visual Studio and I have a table with an attribute set to allow nulls, I try to get a query excluding null values like so:

```
var playerQueryDel = (from p in DB.Jugadores
                                      where p.goles != null
                                      orderby p.goles
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          tiros = p.tirosPorteria,
                                          goles = p.goles,
                                          nombre = p.nombreJugador
                                      }
                    ).ToList();
```

Where `goles` is an attribute of type int that accepts nulls and I know that there are some records in the database with null values in this attribute, the problem is that is returns "empty" values, for example trying this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Testing: {playerQueryDel[0]}");
```

Prints this:

```
Testing:
```

I also try to print to know if it is emptry like so:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{playerQueryDel[0] == null}");
```

Prints `false`, what is the cause of this "not null but empty" value and is there a way to check without having to parse it to something else?
I'll upload more information if needed :)

Comment: What do you believe `playerQueryDel[0]` would print? How does the compiler know how to turn your anonymous type to a string?

Comment: You know you can also debug your code and see what `playerQueryDel` really contains, technology is amazing these days.

Comment: What if you do `WriteLine($"Testing: {playerQueryDel[0].goles}");`

Comment: Or you could create a `class Player { public int Shots { get; set; } public int Goals { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } public override ToString() { return Name; } }`  and then select a new one of those in your query, so you end up with a strongly typed `IEnumerable<Player>`.

Comment: what is the result of playerQueryDel[0].goles == String.Empty;?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try: Check that the list contains any items. Check the individual field in the result being returned.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Testing: {playerQueryDel.Count}");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Testing: {playerQueryDel[0].goles}");
```